# Limit characters or provide validation for input in TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

**Goal:** I would like to limit SwiftUI TextField input by having 3 characters maximum.

**Result:** For some reason there is a way to input more than 3 characters into TextField

**Steps:**

1. Enter "123" to text field
2. Start typing multiple times "4"
3. You'll see that for the each third input there will be "1234" inside the textfield

**Additional info**

- print from `getter` and `setter` doesn't print "1234" output which is really weird
- please check below gif

**Question**: How to limit/validate SwiftUI TextField input for given example?

[image: gif]

Playground code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var inputValue: String = ""
    @State var previousValue: String = ""

    func getter() -> String {
        print("getter called with ", inputValue)
        return inputValue
    }

    func setter(_ newValue: String) {
        print("setter called with ", inputValue)
        if newValue.count > 3 {
            inputValue = previousValue
        } else {
            inputValue = newValue
            previousValue = inputValue
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: .init(get: getter, set: setter))
            .frame(minWidth: 100)
    }
}


PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Also, even if you update the TextField definition like:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: .init(get: { "test "}, set: { _ in }))
            .frame(minWidth: 100)
    }
```

to force "test" value always you still be able to input in every third attempt the additional character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be handled with `.onChange` view modifier. Apologies if my syntax is a bit off, don't have my IDE immediately available.

In SwiftUI, you should never really use direct getters and setters.

```
  @State var yourText = ""

  var body: some View {
      VStack {
          // Your Text w/ @State Binding
      }
      .onChange(of: yourText) { newValue in 
          // Handle your constraints here. 
          // Check your value, if it exceeds your 3 char
          // reset it back to the limit. 
      }
  }
```

#### Update for 2023 | iOS 17+

`.onChange` has been changed to directly use the `yourText` binding value inside of the closure, instead of the closure property.

```swift
.onChange(of: yourText) {
    // Handle your constraints here. 
    // Use the `yourText` binding property instead of capturing `newValue`
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it solves the problem.  
However, I'm still wondering why with using biding there is this weird behaviour

Comment: That's because an @Binding has a `wrappedValue` and a `publishedValue` the `didSet` isn't hit until the wrappedValue is updated. If you use state to update, the wrapped value isn't updated until the view is fully re-rendered, and logic is set. In short the published value never reaches the didSet the way you're expecting because before it can, it's value is already updated.

Comment: I wanted to set the color of the text to red if you went over a certain number of characters, so to force the view to redraw, in the `.onChange` event, I'm adding (or removing if it's already there) an invisible space to the end of the List's header text, which causes a redraw and the color change to occur immediately. In case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.onChange` modifier for every state property.

```
@State private var txtUsername: String = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("enter username", text: $txtUsername)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    }
    .onChange(of: txtUsername, perform: { newValue in
        print("newValue \(newValue)")
    })
}
```

The `newValue` from closure would appends the every char that entered by end user in  TextField as well. So in the closure you can add the logic for number of char limit.